# codeigniter. Eliminar un dato especifico en DataTable

Tags: php, javascript, datatables, codeigniter, modal

Soy muy nuevo en esto.

Cuando yo quiero eliminar una ID en mi tabla digamos la ID #36 y me elimina mi ultima ID que seria la ID 50 y no la ID que yo seleccione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en otras palabras el modal no identifica que ID estoy seleccionando para eliminarlo por lo cual me identifica la ultima ID.

categoria.php

```
<td>
  <a onclick="return confirm_modal();" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xs" style="color:white"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
  <a onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo base_url();?>modal/popup/edit_enquiry_category/<?php echo $row['enquiry_category_id'];?>')" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
</td>
```

modal.php

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_modal(delete_url)
{
  jQuery('#modal-4').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});
}
</script>

<!-- (Normal Modal)-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-4">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content redondo-arriba redondo-abajo" style="margin-top:100px;">

      <div class="modal-header redondo-arriba">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:left;"><strong style="color:#FFFFFF">CONFIRMATION&nbsp;!!!</strong></h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer" align="center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-7">ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE THIS INFORMATION ?</div>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/enquiry_category/delete/<?php echo $row['enquiry_category_id'];?>"  class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check">&nbsp;</i>Delete</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times">&nbsp;</i>Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

no se como hacer que el modal identifique la ID que seleccione para que sea eliminado.

Comment: Estas creando un modal para cada fila?

Comment: No, es un modala en general. para que se entienda estoy creando un modal por cada fila. lo que voy en cada fila esta enumerada por ID y si yo quiero borrar la ID 36 clicleo al boton borrar de esa fila "36" me abre un modal de alerta de confirmación pero esa alerta "modal" no me detecta la ID "36" me detecta la ultima ID que seria el 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun lo que entiendo, debes crear cada fila enviando el id que necesitas eliminar, es decir en tu parte de codigo:

```
... onclick="return confirm_modal();" ...
```

cambiarlo por:

```
... onclick="return confirm_modal(<?php echo $row['enquiry_category_id'];?>);" ...
```

y en la función **confirm_modal**(delete_url)

Asignarle a la etiqueta  la url personalizada :

```
function confirm_modal(id)
{
  var url = '<?php echo base_url() . "admin/enquiry_category/delete/" ;?>';
  $("#url-delete").attr('href', url+id);
  jQuery('#modal-4').modal('show', {backdrop: 'static'});

}
```

y el link "delete" dentro del modal, lo dejas vacio y con la id **url-delete**

```
<a href="#"  class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check">&nbsp;</i>Delete</a>
```

Comment: exactamente eso lo necesitaba me funciono. muchas gracias te lo agradezco